# How to 'case' an argument

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script that can either filter in time interval or not. How do I `case` them up, so the if the "from" parameter exists and "to" parameter doesn't exists, then it will execute the function that only filters only the first argument. eg: myscript.sh --from 18:00 --to 20:00

I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
FROM_TIME_ARGUMENT=$1
FROM_TIME=$2

TO_TIME_ARGUMENT=$3
TO_TIME=$4

FILTER_TIME()
{
    #... i don't know
}

FILTER_TIME
```

and I got stuck on writing the case for it.

Comment: have you tried using [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the getopt function. See 'man getopt' or google it.

```
while getopts ab: ooptdo
case $oopt in
    a) var1=1;;
    b) var2=$OPTARG;;    
    esac
done
```

will walk through your options "-a -b xyz".